# How do i filter the accident table (OSHA) by the load_dt field using API V2 curl methodology?

Tags: labor

I am submitting the following url on the OSHA site, and it doesn't appear to filter the data properly.  My understanding is the below url should filter accident table by LOAD_DT column and the 2020-05-31 date is considered a start date.   Therefore, it would retrieve first 200 results for records that have a LOAD_DT greater or equal to 2020-05-31.  I am getting results where LOAD_DT = 2019-07-22.  Your help would be appreciated.

https://data.dol.gov/get/accident/format/json/limit/200/date_column/LOAD_DT/2020-05-31

Comment: Hey, kind of old thread but waned to know if you ever found a solution. I'm currently trying to do any type of date filtering but am getting a "not acceptable, check suggested format." 

Also I think your URL is missing the `/start_date/` indicated by the api docs.
https://data.dol.gov/get/accident/format/json/limit/200/date_column/LOAD_DT/start_date/2020-05-31